# prove that $dim(w_1 \cap w_2)=0 \Rightarrow w_1\cap w_2 =\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying from a summary, and there I found a proof in which it's claimed that, if we have two finite dimensional subspaces $w_1, w_2$ such that $dim(w_1\cap w_2)=0 \Rightarrow w_1 \cap w_2=\{0\}$.
But it doesn't seem right, cause as I understand it $dim (w_1\cap w_2)=0$ means the power of a Base set for $w_1\cap w_2$ is $0$ so how can I represent the $0$ vector?

Comment: What do you mean by "power of a base set"?

Comment: means the number of vectors in a base for $w_1\cap w_2$ is 0

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up with the basis of the kernel of a linear transformation. The point here is that the intersection of the subspaces intersect only in the zero vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The intersection of two subspaces is a subspace.
2. The only space with dimension zero is $\operatorname{span} \varnothing = \{0\}$.

Comment: Can you please explain why span$\emptyset = \{0\}$?

Comment: @dan: Perhaps have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum